# Spring Database configuration

Tags: spring, hibernate, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

I have faced with one problem that made me crazy in its resolution. The problem is following: when I configure connection with my database in java class - it works good i.e. tables in DB are created corresponding to my classes names. BUT. When I try to use application.properties file instead java class configuration, everything what names tables properly is ignored and I`m confused what can I do with this issue(

For instance: I have a class named as 'ATMResearcher'. When I use java class to configure, there is an 'ATMResearcher' table in my database. But when my configuration properties are described in app.properties file (without using configuration class), then there is an 'atm_researcher' table in DB

I hope, anybody helps me. I provide screenshots of my config class and application.properties file below.

---

application.properties:

```
spring.datasource.url=jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDB
spring.datasource.username=name
spring.datasource.password=password
spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver
hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect

spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create
```

---

JpaConfig.java file:

```
@EnableJpaRepositories(basePackages = "repositories")
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
public class JpaConfig {

    private LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean entityManagerFactory() {

        LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean em
                = new LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean();
        em.setDataSource(dataSource());
        em.setPackagesToScan("entities");
        JpaVendorAdapter vendorAdapter = new HibernateJpaVendorAdapter();
        em.setJpaVendorAdapter(vendorAdapter);
        em.setJpaProperties(additionalProperties());
        return em;
    }

    private DataSource dataSource(){
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();
        dataSource.setDriverClassName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver");
        dataSource.setUrl("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/someDB");
        dataSource.setUsername("name");
        dataSource.setPassword("password");
        return dataSource;
    }

    @Bean
    public PlatformTransactionManager transactionManager(){
        JpaTransactionManager transactionManager = new JpaTransactionManager();
        transactionManager.setEntityManagerFactory((EntityManagerFactory) entityManagerFactory());

        return transactionManager;
    }

    @Bean
    public PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor exceptionTranslation(){
        return new PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor();
    }

    private Properties additionalProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();
        properties.setProperty("hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto", "create");
        properties.setProperty(
                "hibernate.dialect", "org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect");
        return properties;
    }
}
```

ATMResearcher.java

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "ATMResearcher")
@Table(name = "ATMResearcher")
@NamedQueries({
        @NamedQuery(name = ATMResearcher.findByAtm, query = "from ATMResearcher i where i.atm=:name")})
public class ATMResearcher implements Serializable {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 2046903428407635527L;
    public static final String findBy = "researcherAtm.findByAtm";

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;
    private String researcher;
    @ColumnDefault(value = "1")
    private float volume;
    @OneToMany(mappedBy = "atmReseacher", cascade = CascadeType.MERGE, targetEntity = ATMEval.class)
    private Set<ATMEval> atmEval;

    public String getShortName() {
        return Arrays.stream(researcher.split(" ")).filter(n -> n.length() > 2)
                .map(n -> n.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase()).collect(Collectors.joining());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ATMResearcher{" +
                "id=" + id +
                ", researcher='" + discipline + '\'' +
                '}';
    }

}
```

Comment: Try to use `spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect` instead of `hibernate.dialect`.

Comment: @SternK, thanks for your reply, but it doesn`t still works...

Comment: also, you can try to use annotation @PropertySource("classpath:application.properties") for JpaConfig class, then inject Environment env and get props in this way env.getProperty("org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect")

Comment: @Evgeniy but I don`t wanna use configuration file at all. Just hand off this work to spring boot with certain properties in my app.props file.

Comment: What do you mean with "everything what names tables properly is ignored"?

Comment: @JRichardsz for instance: I have a class named as 'ATMResearcher'. When I use configuration file, there is an 'ATMResearcher' table in my database. But when my configuration properties are described in app.properties file (without using configuration class), then there is an 'atm_researcher' table in DB.

Comment: Please attach a piece of your ATMResearcher.java. I think your issue is related to an annotation in your pojo. Also add your ATMResearcher sentence example to the question.

Comment: Note that this `spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto` is passed from spring-data-jpa to hibernate, which translates into hibernate's hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto. This instead `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto`, in your config class, is set directly at hibernate level.

Comment: @lainatnavi I grasped it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think, you are missing this :

```
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

If it works, your properties should look like this:

```
spring.datasource.driverClassName=
spring.datasource.url=
spring.datasource.username=
spring.datasource.password=
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto=create

spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL8Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.physical-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.PhysicalNamingStrategyStandardImpl
```

Comment: If you don’t set the table or column name in an annotation, Hibernate uses one of its implicit naming strategies.  You need to use physical when writing your custom one.

Comment: @JRichardsz I used custom tablenames which I set in annotations, but it didn`t work. Then I followed your recommendation to write additional property down to my app.props file and this resolved my issue.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry but I don't really get it what you mean by "when I configure connection with my database in java class - it works good".

But when looking at you code there is something that you might have not seen yet.
You are using camelcase in you table name. This results in table name "atm_reasearch".

```
@Data
@Entity(name = "ATMResearcher")
@Table(name = "ATMResearcher")
```

Hope this solves your problem.

Comment: It will solve , but you need manually define for every entity  , its better to use explicit strategy

Comment: @MykhailoMoskura you're right but he is using it in his example and asking why.

Comment: I meant that tables are being created with the same name as my entity classes have. But when I use 'application.properties' file - table names are such a 'atm_research' as a result. Physical strategy proposed by JRichardsz and Mykhaylo Moskura helped my. Thank everyone!)

Answer (score 0):

Hello you need to declare the naming strategies in your application.yml or properties file
By default spring will have such behaviour:

- Replace dots with underscores
- Change camel case to snake case
- Lower-case table names

---

You should use JPA compliant standart

For JPA 1.0

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
```

For JPA 2.0

```
spring:
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      naming:     
        implicit-strategy: org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyJpaCompliantImpl
```

For having same names use physical strategy

Comment: Thank you! Physical strategy came in handy)

Comment: Thanks for response